# Stripe "No such token: Stripe Token"

Tags: stripe

Having problems getting Stripe working.

Joomla: 3.9.4
CiviCRM: 5.11 (is this a problem?)
Stripe extension: 5.3.2
Stripe API: 2019-2-19

Getting this result on the contribute page:

> Failed to create Stripe Customer: Payment Response:  Type:
>   invalid_request_error Code: resource_missing Message: No such token:
>   Stripe Token

Stripe shows this:

> Request POST body {   "description": "My test name (CiviCRM)",
>   "card": "Stripe Token",   "email": "tester@jonssweb.net",
>   "metadata": {
>       "civicrm_contact_id": "15"   } }
>
> Response body {   "error": {
>       "code": "resource_missing",
>       "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
>       "message": "No such token: Stripe Token",
>       "param": "card",
>       "type": "invalid_request_error"   } }

I've been scouring the forums for ideas to try and have checked my API keys many, many times.  We have Stripe working fine with Wild Apricot.   Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like something isn't quite right on the front-end. Do you have the javascript or a link to the page being used to generate a token? The literal string value "Stripe Token" is being passed off to your backend here, rather than a token id, which should look something like `tok_xxyyyyyzz`

Comment: Correct, this is the script on the front end form page:
<input id="stripe-token" class="payproc-metadata" name="stripe_token" type="hidden" value="Stripe Token" />

Comment: Any javascript errors in the browser console when you load your checkout page? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/ 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console

Comment: Yes, quite a few errors in fact, here's an example of a 404: 
/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Core/BillingBlock.js?r=UmUQd. 
I went looking for this file and instead of being in that path, the file is under the /Administration/components/com_civicrm/civicrm...etc.   
Not sure if the site is supposed to know to go there, or if it's an installation problem?

Comment: Changing the resource URL's to absolute values has fixed the primary problem of the extension not loading, Stripe is now working properly.  However, I'm still getting an error upon submission of a test contribution (member signup) form.  
"One of parameters (value: ) is not of the type Boolean" This me be unrelated, and will update the post when I figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Turned out to be a problem with my Resource URL paths. Changed from the relative CiviCRM URL variables to absolute paths.

Comment: See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/joomla/issues/5

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, running under Drupal.  Resolution was also a Resource URL.  The page not found error was for:
    sites/default/files/civicrm/**ext**/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/js/civicrm_stripe.js

Civicrm>Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs

Changed Extension Resource URL from
     [civicrm.files]/**ext**/
     to
     [civicrm.files]/**custom_ext**/